# Using multiple @GET

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a class called Book with fields genre and author, i have two separate methods one that gets Books by genre and other that gets book by author, in my code i am not able to retrieve books by author, only by genre works, can some one explain, below is my code

```
@GET
    @Produces({"application/xml"})
    @Consumes({"application/xml"})
    @Path("{genre}")
    public List<book> Find_Book_By_Genre(@PathParam("genre") String genre)
    {
        return  bcontl.getBookByGenre(genre);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/xml"})
    @Consumes({"application/xml"})
    @Path("{author}")
    public List<book> getBookByAuthor(@PathParam("author") String author, @Context HttpHeaders headers)
    {
        return  bcontl.getBookByAuthor(author);
    }
```

Comment: There is no way to distinguish those endpoints, consider adding something to the path (e.g `/genre` , `/author`) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resource method definition is *ambiguous* for JAX-RS and it won't work. You can consider the solution described in [Jeroen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279121/1426227), but I would recommend you a different approach.

Once your main resource is a *book* and you want to filter a *collection of books*, I would advise you to use **query parameters**:

```java
@Path("books")
public class BookResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Book> findBooks(@QueryParam("genre") String genre,
                                @QueryParam("author") String author) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your requests will be like:

- `GET /api/books`: Get a representation of all books.
- `GET /api/books?genre=mistery`: Get a representation of all books that match the genre.
- `GET /api/books?author=john`: Get a representation of all books that match the author.
- `GET /api/books?genre=mistery&author=john`: Get a representation of all books that match both the genre and the author.

This approach makes it easier to introduce other filters if you need to.

Comment: Thank you for the input, do i have a create a method that takes two parameters, public List<Book> FindBooks(String genre, String author), i am using hibernate, so my JSQL query needs to retrive records on either genre or author

Comment: @RampageJoe Yes. You can create a method that take both parameters: genre and author. I've added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both methods have a **wildcard** path, which makes it hard for a framework to decide which method should handle the request, therefor the first matching method is chosen. Try with:

```
@Path("/genre/{genre}")
```

and

```
@Path("/author/{author}")
```